# when should use scala-compiler and when should use scala-library

Tags: scala

I am using scala in android. And I want to include some basic library to the project, and I found there are 2 jar one is scala-compiler  and another is scala-library. What's the difference between them, and how should we choose one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scala-compiler](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler) - is a compiler itself, which (simply saying) takes .scala files and compiles them into the .class files. You don't need it to run already compiled .jar/.class file if you don't interpret scala-code in runtime (which usually you don't). Scala-compiler.jar is used by your built-tool/ide to compile your scala code. Sometimes third-party libraries may also want it as transitive dependency.

[Scala-library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) - is a library that contains scala API (built-in functions, collections, concurrency etc.). Usually (99,9%) you need this.